# Embedding Cling in C++ app

Tags: c++, undefined-reference, archlinux, cling

I was on [this page](https://cdn.rawgit.com/root-mirror/cling/master/www/index.html) trying to embedding cling in a C++ app.

I am on ArchLinux, and I installed `cling` via AUR (so I have everything in `/opt/cling`, and when I try to launch the compile command they show on the site, I get a monster `undefined reference` error (63000 lines approx), with stuff linked to `llvm`. For example, one line is :

```
undefined reference to « llvm::BasicBlock::BasicBlock(llvm::LLVMContext&, llvm::Twine const&, llvm::Function*, llvm::BasicBlock*)
```

I also tried with `llvm-config --cxxflags --ldflags --libs all` thinking that it would use all llvm modules, but it seems that I'm still missing something.

([Here is a gist of my makefile](https://gist.github.com/tforgione/88c1d2d487fbc83684a66029bcc6308e))

What would cause this problem and how could I solve it ?

EDIT : I installed AUR package llvm-libs-svn thinking that there would be more libs, but I seem to have the same errors